# MSP patch creation: multiple targets or single target?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msp

I have some sequential MSIs, say p1, p2, p3, p4 and want to make MSP patch. Based on some test, it seems that it's enough to make a patch between only p1 and p4 to apply the patch to any package between p1 and p4. Is this right, or should I make muliple targetted(p1, p2, p3) patch?

Answer (score 0):

So far I only created patches that have all versions (p1, p2 and p3) as targets, to make sure they are all supported. I don't understand how would Windows Installer see them compatible if p1, p2 and p3, have different product codes. Or you have kept the same product code for all of them?

Comment: They have the same product code, but different package codes.